# GNU BASH Command to Change Image Size AND DPI?

Tags: linux, bash, image, imagemagick

How, using Linux `BASH` *(I'm currently using GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu))*, can I convert a JPG image of 2550x3300 pixels at 72 DPI to become 1700x2200 pixels at 200 DPI?

I'm thinking something like ImageMagick might work, but I'm not sure exactly how to invoke it in order to accomplish the above scenario.  I've looked through the docs for the `convert` command *(both `man` and online)*, but I am still very unclear on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this with **ImageMagick**:

```
convert start.jpg -set density 200 -resize 1700x2200 result.jpg
```

---

If using v7 or higher, use:

```
magick start.jpg -set density 200 -resize 1700x2200 result.jpg
```

Comment: I just found that this also works: `convert -density 200 -resize '1700x2200' "start.jpg" "result.jpg"`

Comment: The v7 syntax of `convert INPUT operators OUTPUT` is to be preferred as that works for all versions, whereas v6 is more forgiving and if you write it that way it may not work with v7.

Comment: I prefer your format as well; it makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`convert INPUT.png -set density 200 -geometry 1700x2200 OUTPUT.png`

---

Or, if you are resizing a JPEG file, you can also use the `-quality` flag:

`convert INPUT.jpg -set density 200 -geometry 1700x2200 -quality [1-100] OUTPUT.jpg`

---

*The shell you are using is almost irrelevant in this case. ;)*

Comment: I will inevitably need to perform such resizing on JPEG files at some point, and the `quality` flag to which you brought my attention will be very useful.  Thanks!